# Music21 Python Library will only output Piano sounds

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, music21

I'm using the Music21 library and want to hear each track in the instrument is should be played in from within my jupyter notebook (IPython).

I can successfully output music on different tracks to a midi file and play through timidity, but am unable to hear any tracks other than the Piano (midiProgram = 0) from the IPython player.

I'm currently on Ubuntu 18.04 using music21 v5.7.0. I've also been able to replicate this on my Mac system.

I've tried writing out a stream to a midi file vs. showing it in the notebook and I can only hear the adjusted instruments in the generated midi file.

```py
from music21 import *

core_corp = corpus.corpora.CoreCorpus()
bach_piece = core_corp.search('bwv120.8-a')[0].parse()

bach_piece.show("midi")

for el in bach_piece.recurse():
    if 'Instrument' in el.classes:
        el.activeSite.replace(el, instrument.Trumpet())

bach_piece.show("midi")
```

I expect to hear all trumpet sounds in the second show() call, but still only hear piano. However, when I open up the generated midi file using timidity, I can hear all of them as trumpets.

Digging through some of the source code, I expect it has something to do with the midiPlayer that is generated by the javascript or in the decoding of the base64 encoded midi file, but I don't have any expertise here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, my current workaround is just to use

```py
!timidity <path to file>
```

In my notebook in case anyone else is running this problem.

Comment: The midi player might not be loading the trumpet instrument properly -- you might need to specify that in music21j.  The next version of music21 will have a brand new MIDI player based on the new midicube.js playback, so it won't be too long to wait for it to work.

Comment: Great to hear, thanks @MichaelScottCuthbert!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem about Jupyter Notebook's MIDI player, not about the Music21. You can hear all the instruments' sound when you write&play the MIDI file with correct MIDI player.
For writing MIDI files:

```py
stream1 = converter.parse('d:/musicxml_folder/Rondo_Alla_Turca.xml')
stream1.write('midi', 'd:/musicxml_folder/Rondo_Alla_Turca.mid')
```

For playing the MIDI file, i use Windows Media Player. When i do this in Pycharm IDE

```py
stream1.show('midi')
```

Windows Media Player opens up. If you want to hear the sound of MIDI file on another environment you can use a library that can play MIDI files.